# Pivot in LINQ using lambda expression

Tags: linq

I am writing a lambda in linq for getting the pivoted data from the resulting list.For getting the pivoting columns am setting a where condion to get the value.the problem here is am getting default value if the where condtion fails.I dont want the column if the where condition fails.Kindly help me out.

```
var query = dataList
    .GroupBy(c => c.IpAddress)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        IPAddress = g.Key,
        AssetType = g.ElementAtOrDefault(0).AssetTypeName,
        AssetName = g.ElementAtOrDefault(0).AssetName,
        //if where condition fails i dont need this column.
        //also am giving c.DsName == "Active Calls" ,how to achieve tis dynamically
        **ActiveCalls = g.Where(c => c.DsName == "Active Calls").Sum(c => c.CurrentValue),**
        **HoldCalls = g.Where(c => c.DsName == "Hold Calls").Sum(c => c.CurrentValue),**
        **CPU = g.Where(c => c.DsName == "CPU").Sum(c => c.CurrentValue),**
    });
```

Comment: There's no need to add an answer to edit your question...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a value to hold the sum and then specify its a type in another column. That way you don't have to deal with null columns. (The assumption is that only one type is valid at a time).

```
Value   = g.Sum(c => c.CurrentValue), // Value as specified by the the DsName property. 
DsName  = c.DsName
```